# In Box2D, how to fix body's rotation

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d

[image]
[image]

i'm using cocos2d-x's box2d.

like this picture, my char has box shape body,

and my char rotates when hit.

but i want my char's body didn't rotate.

I know how sprite didn't rotate.

but I don't know how to fix body's rotate.

---

myChar's code

```
    void HelloWorld::makeMe()
    {   
        Sprite* pSprite = Sprite::create("shipBeige_manned.png");
        pSprite->setPosition(Vec2(100,100));
        this->addChild(pSprite);    
        b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.Set(100 / PTM_RATIO, 100 / PTM_RATIO);
        bodyDef.userData = pSprite;

        b2Body* body = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

        b2PolygonShape pho;
        pho.SetAsBox(1.24f, 1.22f); 

        b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

        fixtureDef.shape = &pho;

        fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;

        fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;

        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
        body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);


        pSprite->setName("me");
    }
```

---

update(tick) code

```
    void HelloWorld::tick(float dt)
    {   


        int velocityIterations = 8;
        int positionIterations = 3;

        _world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);


        for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
        {
            if (b->GetUserData() != nullptr) {
                Sprite* spriteData = (Sprite *)b->GetUserData();
                spriteData->setPosition(Vec2(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                    b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO));
                spriteData->setRotation(-1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using SetFixedRotation to my Char's body.

```
    void HelloWorld::makeMe()
    {   
        Sprite* pSprite = Sprite::create("shipBeige_manned.png");
        pSprite->setPosition(Vec2(100,100));
        this->addChild(pSprite);    
        b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.Set(100 / PTM_RATIO, 100 / PTM_RATIO);
        bodyDef.userData = pSprite;

        b2Body* body = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
        body->SetFixedRotation(true);  <----add this code
        b2PolygonShape pho;
        pho.SetAsBox(1.24f, 1.22f); 

        b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

        fixtureDef.shape = &pho;
            // 밀도
        fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        // 마찰력 - 0 ~ 1
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
        // 반발력 - 물체가 다른 물체에 닿았을때 팅기는 값
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
        body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);


        pSprite->setName("me");
    }
```